# Solving an ODE that equals a constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My ODE is: $y''=W/H$. ($W$ and $H$ are both constants)

I was told that I could use the method undetermined coefficients to solve this but I got stuck. I was thinking I could take the integral of it twice with respect to $x$?

I know the homogeneous equation is $y_h = C_1 + x C_2$ but after that I am stuck.

If I can use any other method that would be fine as well.

Please explain in detail. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are $W$ and $H$ both constants? If so, just write $c = \dfrac{W}{H}$ and simplify matters. Hint: Just integrate both sides twice as one approach. Note: this site uses MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''=\frac{W}{H}$$
$$y'=\frac{W}{H}x+c_2$$
$$y=\frac{W}{H}\frac{x^2}{2}+c_2x+c_1$$
$(c_1+c_2x)$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation (case $\frac{W}{H}=0$)

$\frac{W}{H}\frac{x^2}{2}$ is the particular solution (case $c_1=c_2=0$)

Answer (score 0):

the homognous D.E
$$y''=0$$
the characteristics equation is
$$r^2=0$$
$$r_1=0,r_2=0$$
so, the complementary solution is
$$y_c=c_1e^{0.x}+c_2xe^{0.x}=c_1+c_2x$$
to find the particular solution, let
$$y_p=Ax^2$$
so
$$y'_p=2Ax$$
$$y''_p=2A$$
substitute them
$$2A=\frac{W}{H}$$
$$A=\frac{W}{2H}$$